# Cross origin security error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, cross-domain, webgl

I'm trying to make a userscript that allows a player to have a custom flair for his player shown on just the local browser. The function that returns the flair texture in the game makes a canvas that gets the right section of the flair image which holds all the flairs, then makes a PIXI texture out of that. Whenever I try assign my own PIXI texture to the player, whose source is a picture on imgur, I get the error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': Tainted canvases may not be loaded.
```

Does anybody know if there is a way to get around this?

For context: Here is the flair texture function:

```
tagpro.renderer.getFlairTexture = function(e, t) {
    var n = PIXI.TextureCache[e];
    if (!n) {
        var r = document.createElement("canvas");
        r.width = 16, r.height = 16;
        var i = r.getContext("2d");
        i.drawImage($('#flair').get(0), t.x * 16, t.y * 16, 16, 16, 0, 0, 16, 16), n = PIXI.Texture.fromCanvas(r), PIXI.TextureCache[e] = n
    }
    return n
}
```

where `$("#flair").get(0)` is just an image whose source is from the actual games website (http://static.koalabeast.com/images/flair.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
var img = $('#flair').get(0);
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
i.drawImage(img, t.x * 16, t.y * 16, 16, 16, 0, 0, 16, 16);
```

Comment: Well that doesn't cause any errors, but I need to change the images source I'm pretty sure

Comment: thankyou so much man, I have no clue what you did but it works